# Criar um meio para não repetir meu código

Tags: c#

Como posso criar um meio de **simplificar** o código abaixo para que não se repitam algumas coisas?

Gostaria que o meu código "**Gera usuário**" não se repetisse ao longo do **IF**.

Como devo proceder?

```
if (txtNome.Text == ""){
    MessageBox.Show("Digite o nome do usuário.", "Name", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    txtNome.Focus();
}else if (txtEmail.Text == ""){
    MessageBox.Show("Digite o seu endereço de e-mail.", "Mail", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    txtEmail.Focus();
}else if (txtSenha.Text == ""){
    MessageBox.Show("Digite a sua senha.", "Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    txtSenha.Focus();
}else if (RdAdministrador.Checked == true){
    string resposta="xxxxx";
    string res = Interaction.InputBox("Você é realmente um administrador?\nDigite a resposta para a pergunta secreta.", "Pergunta Secreta");
    if (res == resposta){
        MessageBox.Show("Acesso concedido!");
        //Gera usuário ********************************************************************************************
        int i = txtNome.Text.LastIndexOf(" "); //Carrega na variavel o valor do ultimo espaço para pegar sobrenome.

        string nome = txtNome.Text.Substring(0, 1); //Carrega primeira letra do nome digitado.

        string sobrenome = txtNome.Text.Substring(i + 1); //Carrega ultimo sobrenome completo.

        Random GeraRandom = new Random(); //Gera numero randomico para adicionar ao usuário.
        int numero = GeraRandom.Next(1, 99);

        txtUsuario.Text = sobrenome + nome + numero;
        //**********************************************************************************************************
    }else{
        MessageBox.Show("Acesso negado, Adeus!", "Good-bye", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
}else{
    //Gera usuário ********************************************************************************************
    int i = txtNome.Text.LastIndexOf(" "); //Carrega na variavel o valor do ultimo espaço para pegar sobrenome.

    string nome = txtNome.Text.Substring(0, 1); //Carrega primeira letra do nome digitado.

    string sobrenome = txtNome.Text.Substring(i + 1); //Carrega ultimo sobrenome completo.

    Random GeraRandom = new Random(); //Gera numero randomico para adicionar ao usuário.
    int numero = GeraRandom.Next(1, 99);

    txtUsuario.Text = sobrenome + nome + numero;
    //**
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia criar uma função `gerar_usuario()` e dentro desta função colocar o código de criar usuários e depois só chamar a função onde você precisar.

Comment: Gerei uma função public void GeraUsuário () e funcionou. Era fácil assim e eu não me lembrava... obrigado Flavio!!!

Answer (score 2):

Crie classes.
Faça programação-orientada-a-objetos, criando classes com métodos, funções, variáveis, etc... 
Você pode criar uma classe "gerador_de_usuario" e dentro dela botar uma função `gerar_usuário(string nome, string email, string senha)`, assim ficará mais organizado.

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão:
Faça as validações na model.
No seu código, você precisará apenas de um try catch.

Exemplo:
Modelo

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name)){throw new Exception("O nome é obrigatório")}
```

Já no código apresentado:

```
try{...}catch(Exception ex){...}
```